# Big O-Notation Proof

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the following task:

> Use Taylor's Theorem to proof that for $f \in C^3$, the following holds:
>   $$f'(x) - \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} \in O(h^3)$$

I am not really used to this $O$ notation, so I dont have a clue how to approach this.
I'd really appreciate if someone could give me a hint, a tip or the proof.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Use the definition of big O when you have trouble.

Comment: The task is wrong, you will only get $O(h^2)$. Example: $f(x)=x^3$, $f'(x)=3x^2$, $f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=3x^2-(3x^2+h^2)=-h^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extended mean value theorem with $x$ constant and $h$ as variable to transform
$$
\frac{2f'(x)h-f(x+h)+f(x-h)}{2h^3}
\\=\frac{2f'(x)-f'(x+h_1)-f'(x-h_2)}{6h_1^2}
\\=\frac{-f''(x+h_2)+f''(x-h_2)}{12h_2}
\\=-\frac{f'''(x+h_3)}{6}
$$
where $|h_3|<h_2<h_1<h$. Thus
$$
f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=-\frac{f'''(\xi)}6·h^2
$$
with $\xi\in (x-h,x+h)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. write out a 2nd order taylor series for $f$ at $x$. It'll tell you something about $f(x+u)$ in terms of $f(x)$. $f'(x)$, etc., and $u$. If it tells you something about $f(a+h)$ in terms of $f(a)$ and $h$, substitute variables until it looks like
   \begin{align}
   f(x+u) = f(x) + f'(x)\cdot u + ...+ O(\text{something}) 
   \end{align}
   (The big-O may have some other form, but that's OK).
2. Now apply the formula you got to $u = h$ *and* to $u = -h$. Add the results and simplify.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. This is what I have done so far:
$f(x+h)=f(x) + f'(x)h + f''(x)h^2 + R_1(x+h)$, with $R_1(x+h)=\frac{f'''(\xi _1)}{6}h^3$ and $f(x-h)=f(x) + f'(x)(-h) + f''(x)h^2 + R_2(x-h)$ with $R_1(x-h)=\frac{f'''(\xi _2)}{6}(-h)^3$ using Lagranges error expression. This gives me the following term:
$f'(x)-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} = \frac{-h^2(f'''(\xi_1 )+f'''(\xi_2))}{12}$.
Am I on the right track? I am not quite sure how to proceed!